# HTML / JS Table - Calculating based on input numbers

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

## Goal

I am trying to implement a dynamic feature in my table.
Basically, what I want to do is the following:

### Problem definition

**1)** 
Write 2 number values(PROGNOSE_EXP, PROGNOSE_MAIL) in my two input td's in the table (DONE)

**2)** 
In the column HOURS_USED, I want it to take into account, the given numbers inserted into the input fields e.g: (300 / 9) + (900 / 9) = 133 hours used on the given input values, 300 and 900, so instead of hardcoding the number 133 in the picture, it should calculate it.

[image: f]

#### Variables in calculation

```
AVG_EXP_TIME = 9
<br>
AVG_MAIL_TIME = 9
<br>
PROGNOSE_EXP = 300
<br>
PROGNOSE_MAIL = 900<br>
HOURS_USED = 133
```

---

## Code:

```
var th = document.createElement('th');
th.className = "hours_used";
var text = document.createTextNode("Hours used")
th.appendChild(text);
row.appendChild(th);

var th = document.createElement('th');
th.className = "prognose_eks";
th.id = "digit_fast_header"
var text = document.createTextNode("Prognose exp")
th.appendChild(text);
row.appendChild(th);

var th = document.createElement('th');
th.className = "prognose_mail";
var text = document.createTextNode("Prognose mail")
th.appendChild(text);
row.appendChild(th);


tbl.appendChild(row);
var tblBody = tbl.createTBody();

var td = document.createElement('td');
td.className = "hoursUsed";
td.innerHTML = "133"; 
tr.appendChild(td);
    
var td = document.createElement('td');
td.className = "inputEks";
td.id = "inputEks" 
td.innerHTML = "<input type='number' class='inpt_text' name = 'inpt[]' >";
tr.appendChild(td);

var td = document.createElement('td');
td.className = "inputMail";
td.id = "inputMail" 
td.innerHTML = "<input type='number' class='inpt_text' name = 'inpt[]' >";
tr.appendChild(td);
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or code snippet? It will be hard to help if we don't know what js functions you already have implemented or even your basic html table.

Comment: I need to fetch value of both input fields and do calculations and return the calculation in the hours used field.

Comment: I know what you need to do, I was just asking if you had any working code to show a code snippet or jsfiddle?